# C# How do you get the listviewItem/row from the AfterLabelEdit event?

Tags: c#, listview, event-handling

**Goal :** I'm trying to update a Dictionary when the label is changed/edited on my Listview

**Problem:** I don't know how to retreive the row/ListViewItem from the row that triggers AfterLabelEdit

My class is subcribing to the event

```
myListView.AfterLabelEdit +=new LabelEditEventHandler(myListView_AfterLabelEdit);
```

I'm handeling the event with the function

```
        private void myListView_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Renamed Me to: "+e.Label.ToString());


            if (deviceDictionary.ContainsKey(***)) <--I need to retreive this row that was edited
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Entry updated");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd look at the contents of `LabelEditEventArgs`, either according to intellisence, or [in the debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging), and see if you can find something.  That's normally where that sort of information can be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`AfterLabelEditEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.afterlabeledit.aspx) event passes an object of type [`LabelEditEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventargs.aspx) as a parameter to the handler method. This parameter is named `e`; you already show it as part of the event handler method's signature.

One of the properties of this class, accessible through `e`, is [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventargs.item.aspx), which returns the zero-based index of the [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) that is being edited.

Once you have this zero-based index, you can use that retrieve the appropriate item from your `ListView` control's [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) property:

```
// Retrieve the item that is being edited.
ListViewItem item = myListView.Items[e.Item];
```

And once you have the correct `ListViewItem`, you can query its properties. What I think you mean by "key" is exposed as the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name.aspx) property.

```
private void myListView_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Renamed Me to: " + e.Label.ToString());

    if (deviceDictionary.ContainsKey(myListView.Items[e.Item].Name))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entry updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you greatly. although Items is non-invocable as a method

Comment: Yeah, of course it's not. Answering too many VB questions lately.

Comment: Thanks again, This was most helpful! :)